# validate particular column and its value using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Validate Status Column using powershell. If any status column contain Not-compliant then overall status column needs to be displayed not-compliant. Attached data for your reference.

Trying below code but not getting expected output.

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\Desktop\DDPC1.csv

$csv | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Status -eq "Not-Compliant") {
        Echo "The system is $($_.Status) in $($_.Parameter)"
    }else
    {Write-Host "System is Fully compliant in All Parameter"
    }
}
```

*In Case of multiple parameter non-compliant,* output needs to be **The system is Not-Compliant in Patching and GoogleChrome**. But Getting below output.

**System is Fully compliant in All Parameter**

**The system is Not-Compliant in Patching**

**The system is Not-Compliant in Chrome**

**System is Fully compliant in All Parameter**

*In Case of compliant,* output needs to be **The system is Fully Compliant in all parameter**. But Getting below output.

**System is Fully compliant in All Parameter**

**System is Fully compliant in All Parameter**

**System is Fully compliant in All Parameter**

**System is Fully compliant in All Parameter**

**CSV Data: -**

| Parameter | Version | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Windows 11 | 20H2 | Compliant |
| Patching | NA | Not-Compliant |
| Chrome | 10.1 | Not-Compliant |
| Overall | NA |  |

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Actual issue remains same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the sample data, the `overall` data/row doesn't seem to fit into the csv to correlate correctly. Using logic to omit it explicitly seems to make better sense to wrap additional logic to get what you prefer per example output.

Use `arrays` and `counts` along with some math around those counts for the conditions and omit the `overall` row to simplify a bit to get the exact results you seek.

### PowerShell

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\Desktop\DDPC1.csv;
$cnt = ($csv | ? { $_.Parameter -ne "Overall"}).Count
[array]$noncompliant = $csv | ? { $_.Parameter -ne "Overall"-and $_.Status -eq "Not-Compliant"};
[array]$compliant = $csv | ? { $_.Parameter -ne "Overall"-and $_.Status -eq "Compliant"};
$noncompliant | ForEach-Object {"The system is $($_.Status) in $($_.Parameter)"};
$compliant | ForEach-Object {"The system is $($_.Status) in $($_.Parameter)"};
If($noncompliant.Count -eq 0 -and $compliant.Count -eq $cnt) {"The system is Fully Compliant in all parameter"} Else {"The system is Not-Compliant"};
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Counting Objects in PowerShell](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/powershell/counting-objects-in-powershell/)
- [Create and use PowerShell Arrays](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-arrays.html)
- [Where-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/where-object.html)

  > The '`?`' symbol and Where are both aliases for Where-Object. If you
  > explicitly want to run the Where-Object command, run Where-object or
  > '`?`'